# preg_replace Pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i'm not very firm with preg_replace - in other Words i do not really understand - so i hope you can help me.

I have a string in a Text like this one: `[demo category=1]` and want to replace with the Content of Category (id=1) e.g. "`This is the Content of my first Category`"

This is my startpoint Pattern - that's all i have: 
`'/[demo\s*.*?]/i';`

Hope you can help?

Comment: Do you mean you want to replace the string "[demo category=1]" with "Content of Category (id=1)"?

Comment: i have e.g. an array with $content[0]='This is Nr.1' and $content[1]='This is Nr. 2' - now i want to replace [demo category=1] with $content[$categoryid]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you need to escape the square brackets as they are special characters in PCREs:

```
'/\[demo\s*.*?\]/i';
```

Secondly, it sounds like you want to do something with the digit at the end, so you'll want to capture it using parenthesis:

```
'/\[demo\s*.*?=(\d+)\]/i';
```

The braces will capture `\d+` and store it in a reference.  `\d+` will match a string of numbers only.

Finally, it sounds like you need to use [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to perform a special function on the matches in order to get the string you want:

```
function replaceMyStr($matches)
{
    $strNum = array("1"=>"first", "2"=>"second", "3"=>"third"); // ...etc
    return "This is the Content of my ".$strNum($matches[1])." Category.";
    // $matches[1] will contain the captured number
}
preg_replace_callback('/\[demo\s*.*?=(\d+)\]/i', "replaceMyStr", "[demo category=1]");
```

Answer (score 1):

further to the above answers, you have 2 ways to do the actual replacing. assuming you have 10 category names you want to replace, you can either do something like

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $max_category; $i++) {
 $category_name = get_category_name($i);
 $s = preg_replace("/\[demo\s+category=(\d+)\]/i", $category_name, $s);
}
```

or

```
$s = preg_replace_callback("/\[demo\s+category=(\d+)\]/i", "get_category_name", $s);
```

in both cases, get_category_name($id) is a function that will get a category name for an id. you should test both options to evaluate which is faster for your uses.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is going to be like this

```
/\[demo\s+category=(\d+)\]/i'
```

(you need to escape brackets because they're special)

Answer (score 0):

The `[` and `]` characters have special meaning (they denote character classes - ranges and collections of character). You need to escape `[` as `\[` (and evidently in PHP, unlike other regex flavors, you also need to escape `]`). Also I suggest you make use of the character class `[^]]` = match any character that is not a `]`

```
/\[demo\s+[^]]*\]/i
```

should work better.

Edit: If you want to extract the name and number, then you can use

```
/\[demo\s+(\w+)\s*=\s*(\d+)\]/i
```

Comment: Huh. Indeed RegexBuddy suggests this. It does so, too, for other flavors where it's definitely not necessary (like Python). I think RegexBuddy is overly cautious here. I haven't tried it with PHP - sure it doesn't work when `]` is not escaped?

Comment: It does work, but still should be escaped for readability reasons.

Comment: Hm. I find it helps readability to avoid unnecessary backslashes whenever possible. Interestingly, Jan Goyvaerts has blogged about this problem: http://www.regexguru.com/2008/12/dont-escape-literal-characters-that-arent-metacharacters/

Comment: ...and here: http://www.regexguru.com/2008/04/escape-characters-only-when-necessary/ - in that case he advocates escaping the closing `]`. Matter of taste, in the end...